# How To Reduce a Javascript Date Object to a String in this Format: "02/14/2010"

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I convert Javascript Date Objects to a date string in the following format:

**Date Object**

```
2000-01-12 23:00:00.000Z
```

**Resulting String**

```
"01/12/2000 23"
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Try: `(new Date('2000-01-12 23:00:00.000Z')).toLocaleString()`

Comment: @tewathia - `'2000-01-12 23:00:00.000Z'` isn't a valid date string.

Comment: This has been asked soooooo many times. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: @Frogmouth I wouldn't argue with that(I just copied the string from the question), but the Date constructor is incredibly flexible. The code I've written in my comment would work.

Comment: @tewathia - for me `.toLocaleString()` is a nice solution. **+1** for this. But form me, with `'2000-01-12 23:00:00.000Z'`, not work. Try yourself, in console get back `Date {Invalid Date}` but the solution (with well formatted date string) is nice.

Comment: @Frogmouth I did try it in the console, in Chrome V32. I get `>(new Date('2000-01-12 23:00:00.000Z')).toLocaleString();
>"1/13/2000 4:30:00 AM"`. Also, see http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/X7LMP/

Comment: @tewathia ... I believe you, but not seems cross browser :D

Answer (score 3):

```
date.getDate() + '/' +
(date.getMonth() +1) + '/' + 
date.getFullYear() + ' ' +
(date.getHours() + 1)
```

Why the `+1`     you ask? Because javascript. `:(`